# Removing duplicates from a vector, recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I'm working on a program that is supposed to sort a vector of ints and then get passed to a recursive function to remove any duplicates by having an element check it's neighbor, and remove it if they're the same. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void checkNum(vector<int> &v, int n)
{
    int i = n;
    if (v[i] == '\0')
    {
        cout << "No duplicates found." << endl;
    }
    if (v[i]==v[i+1])
    {
        v.erase(v.begin()+i);
        /*return 1 + */checkNum(v, n);
    }
    else
    {
        n++;
        /*return 0 + */checkNum(v, n);
    }
    int k;
    cout << "Sorted values, no duplicates: " << endl;
    for (k=0; k< v.size(); k++)
        cout << v[k] << " ";
    //return 0;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter numbers, 0 to quit: " << endl;
    bool more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        if (num == 0)
            more = false;
        else
            numbers.push_back(num);
    }
    sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());
    cout << "The sorted values are: " << endl;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    checkNum(numbers, 0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My issue here is that when it runs, I get the following error after entering values:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll File: d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector Line: 1140
Expression: vector subscript out of range
```

It also prints multiple times when it works but I'm not terribly concerned about that. Where's the bug? Can anybody help me out?

***UPDATE:***

Here is the code that I am CURRENTLY running with:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int checkNum(vector<int> &v, int n)
{
int i = n;
if (i == v.size())
{
    cout << "No duplicates found." << endl;
    return 0;
}
if (v[i]==v[i+1])
{
    v.erase(v.begin()+i);
    return checkNum(v, n);
}
else
{
    n++;
    return checkNum(v, n);
}

int k;
cout << "Sorted values, no duplicates: " << endl;
for (k=0; k< v.size(); k++)
    cout << v[k] << " " << endl;
return 0;
}

int main()
{
vector<int> numbers;
cout << "Please enter numbers, 0 to quit: " << endl;
bool more = true;
while (more)
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    if (num == 0)
        more = false;
    else
        numbers.push_back(num);
}
sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());
cout << "The sorted values are: " << endl;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    cout << numbers[i] << " ";
checkNum(numbers, 0);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I ran with a debugger, everything was fine, was removing duplicates like it was no big deal, until the size of n/i reached the size of the list. Then I get that error message listed above. How do I fix that?

Comment: What happened when you encountered a breakpoint at line 1140?  What was the value of the subscript when it failed?  I assume you are using a debugger.

Comment: Your're not concerned about indexing past the end of your array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I encountered it, I had options to Abort, Retry or Ignore. Retry gives me the same result, Ignore crashes the program, and I'm sure you know what Abort does.

Not concerned about what?

Comment: @Kyle: Learn to use a debugger. You can google that word.

Comment: use `vec.erase( std::unique(vec.begin(),vec.end()),vec.end);` -- or is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

You have commented out `return`s completely except the recursive call. The functions go on although it should not.

You should use `return checkNum(v, n);` on those lines.

Edit:

Your code is completely flawed and won't do what you want. Here is a quick ugly code of how you should be doing it while you stick to limitation of probably homework:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void checkNum(vector<int> &v, vector<int>::iterator& it)
{
    if (it == v.end() - 1) //last element
    {
        cout << "After duplicate removal pass:" << endl;
        for (int k=0; k< v.size(); k++)
             cout << v[k] << " ";
    }
    else if (*it == *(it + 1)) //next element is equal to current one, erase current one
    {
        v.erase(it); //using 'it' after this line is normally not a good practice,
        // but we know the vector is stored sequentially and 'it' will point to another element because above we checked if this is the last element or not.
        return checkNum(v, it);
    }
    else //next element is not the same as this one
    {
        ++it;
        return checkNum(v, it);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter numbers, 0 to quit: " << endl;
    bool more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        if (num == 0)
            more = false;
        else
            numbers.push_back(num);
    }
    sort(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());
    cout << "The sorted values are: " << endl;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    vector<int>::iterator elementToStart = numbers.begin();
    checkNum(numbers, elementToStart);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Made that change, same issue.

Comment: @Kyle The code is completely flawed. Now that I read it completely, it will say "No duplicates found." already it has found duplicates and removed them because n will eventually be equal to vector size.

Comment: I changed that line to `if (v[i] == '\0')` and I still get the same error when it runs.

Comment: I put your code into my program, compiled/built fine, starts fine, but your code quits quicker than mine does when run through the debugger. Your code removes one or two duplicate elements, then the program fails on me. Can't understand why, this is what I get: `The program '[5504] Project.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).`

Comment: @Kyle It builds and runs fine on  clang. Maybe MSVC debug build adds some padding to vector elements or some kind of protection so iterator don't point the next element properly after erasure. Change iterators ('it') with your old int 'n' and you probably will be fine.

Comment: When I run this code, I get a new error now, saying the iterators are incompatible or incomparable.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it to work.  You need to add a return after the line, cout << "No duplicates found" like:

```
if (i == v.size())
{
   cout << "No duplicates found." << endl;
   return; // add this return
}
```

The reason is that by the time the recursive call reaches this point in the program, you are done checking for duplicates. Your recursive function should wrap things up at this point.

Without the return you keep increasing n (below at the line with n++):

```
else
{
    n++;
    /*return 0 + */checkNum(v, n);
}
```

but then n is larger than the size of your vector v, causing the error.

Comment: @Kyle, not sure what your talking about; look at the part of your code that I referred to above, did I miss something?  I added the return above to illustrate what needed changed.  After this change your code ran perfectly for me.

Comment: @Kyle, as I mentioned above, your code doesn't seem flawed to me, the rest of it runs fine after the simple change I mentioned.

Comment: Must have been a change I made to it that I didn't update here. My mistake.

Comment: @Kyle, ok study the code Tolga sent you, that works good too.  Good luck.